# Hibernate Envers - How to audit changes in an entity that is in a @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Lets say I have two entities, A and B. A has a @OneToMany relationship to B and I have audited all the properties in B. When I use Envers to obtain  the revisions all I get are the changes in the relation between A and B but I also need to obtain the changes in B's properties. Is there a way todo this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag` or setting the `modifiedFlags=true` on the relation's `@Audited` annotation?

Comment: Where do I place the tags? on the relation or in entity B's properties

Comment: Is entity B marked as @auditable?

Comment: Yes, entity B is marked as @Audited.

Comment: How are you modifying Entity A and Entity B?  If you could update your post with your entity mappings, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am working off the presumption of the following mappings:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class EntityA {
    /* other properties & getters/setters */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntityB> bList;
}

@Entity
@Audited
public class EntityB {
    /* other properties & getters/setters */
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityA a;
}
```

Anytime you add/remove an `EntityB` from `EntityA`, this will trigger a revision change associated with `EntityA` as well as the associated `EntityB` that is added/removed due to the relationship.

But if you decide you want to modify some attribute of `EntityB` that has no direct impact upon `EntityA`, there will only be a revision generated for `EntityB` and not `EntityA`, see below.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
final EntityA a = entityManager.find( EntityA.class, aId );
for ( EntityB b : a.getbList() ) {
    b.setName( b.getName() + "-modified" );
}
entityManager.merge( a );
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

If you need the individual revisions of `EntityB` in this case, you'll need to actually specifically query for `EntityB` through the `AuditReader` interface instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tought, I'll try it and let you know.